# EF Include is not working! returning null in a 1 to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, include

i am trying to display a list of cities with a country, a 1 to many relation.
I created the models for both of them:

```
City model
[Key]
        public int ID_Cidade { get; set; 
        public int ID_Pais { get; set; }
        public RH_Pais Pais { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public Boolean Capital { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        public int OrdemCidade { get; set; }
        public List<RH_Escritorios> Escritorios { get; set; }

Country model

[Key]
        public int ID_Pais { get; set; }

        public int ID_Moeda { get; set; }
        public RH_Moeda Moeda { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Nome_completo { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        public int OrdemPais { get; set; }
        public List<RH_Cidades> Cidades { get; set; }
        public List<RH_Idioma_Pais> Idiomas { get; set; }
```

and then i used fluent API to create the relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RH_Cidades>()
            .HasOne(m => m.Pais)
            .WithMany(m => m.Cidades)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ID_Pais);
```

and somehow when i generate the controller with EF, and i go to see the cities it causes a null error...  this is because it has a include of the country when im trying to get the cities..

```
  var rH_EntitiesContext = _context.RH_Cidades.Include(r => r.Pais).ToList();
```

The most annoying part is that i have the exact same situation in another relationship, with 1 to many and the include and it works perfectly!!
I have read and read my code for hours by now and i cannot see why the Include is giving me that error when in the offices controller with the same situation works...
Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: can you post your RH_Cidades model as well to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is actually solved, somehow my model wasnt going for the right table... and recreating the model wasnt enought, i deleted and created the table in the database again and created the model exacly how it was in the database and is working fine... :)